# For what values of $z$ does the series converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Consider the following series:

$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{1}{1+z^{n}}.$$

For what values of $z$ ($z$ complex) does this converge?

Thoughts:

The series $\frac{1}{z^{n}}$ converges for all $|z|>1$. Since $1+z^{n}>z^{n}$, the above series must converge for all $|z|>1$ as well. I wanted to know how one proves rigorously that $\frac{1}{z^{n}}$ converges for all $|z|>1$, and whether this is indeed the radius of convergence for the above series as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inequalities like $1+z^{n}>z^{n}$ have no meaning for complex numbers. The series converges absolutely for $|z|>1$ because $|\frac  1 {1+z^{n}}| \leq \frac 1 {|z|^{n}-1}$ and $\sum \frac 1 {|z|^{n}-1}$ is convergent. For $|z| \leq 1$ the series is not convergent because the general term does not tend to $0$. [It is not even defined for $z=-1$].